# Replacing characters that do not "fit" a certain encoding

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a column in a SQL Server 2008 database (10.0.2841) that I need to insert into another database (10.0.5500). Before I insert into the destination database, I must ensure that the column only contains windows-1252 characters.

I'm currently using an SSIS package to do this. My source query has a pile of "replace"s which works, but it's damn ugly and sure to soon be unmaintainable.

```
select replace(replace(rep.......etc(column, 'º', ''), nchar(0x9D), ''), ......etc from table
```

There's sure to be a better way to do this, but I don't know what it is. So, how do I say in my query (or in a script component perhaps?), "if there's a character in here that doesn't work in this encoding, give me an empty string in its place instead?"

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the collation of youre sourcedb is different from your destination db. Perhaps you can use COLLATE to change the collation to that of the destination db.
For example:

```
SELECT
  column COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably add a Script Transformation to the Data Flow and apply the .NET Framework e.g. Encoding.Convert, ref http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdcak6ye.aspx